# How to override letsencrypt's SSL settings on nginx?

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

After setting up letsencrypt for my server that uses nginx to serve websites, it creates the following lines in my domain's config file:

```
listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

So one of my sites require TLSv1 because of some old Android app. But the default config specified by letsencrypt does not have it.

I then commented out the `include` line above, copied the contents in the `options-ssl-nginx.conf` file, and modified `ssl_protocols` to include TLSv1.

```
listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
#include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";
```

However, after restarting/reloading nginx, the server ignores the changes I have made above and continues to not support TLSv1.

If I edit the `options-ssl-nginx.conf` file to include TLSv1, it works. But all the other sites are affected and I only want it to be applied on 1 website. And whenever the SSL certs are automatically updated, the changes in this file will also be removed.

Comment: If all of the sites share the same IP address, they're talking to the same SSL service, so I don't think you can fine tune the protocols on a server name by server name basis. The best bet would be to move the TLSv1 site to a different IP address so that it can have it's own SSL service.

Comment: So you're saying that the SSL options for nginx are global and apply to all the sites on the same server yea? That explains everything. Thanks!